# Можно ли "взойти на должность"? В каком-нито высоком штиле?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> И не удивительно, что он взошёл на должность Верховного жреца –
>   понтифика.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, причем легко, уже были такие случаи. Хотя в словаре можно взойти только на гору.

Как уточняется на сайте регионального Минэнерго, Чертков **взошел на должность** вице-главы ведомства, сменив на этом посту Владимира Беспалова...

http://global52.ru/news/id/7179

Также: Не успел глава Могилевской области Владимир Доманевский **взойти на должность**, как озвучил довольно спорную среди могилевчан инициативу...

Comment: А нет ли в этих примерах лёгкой иронии? Восходят обычно на престол или трон, иногда на пост. Должность взваливают на себя или возлагают на кого-то - другая "геометрия".

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, в подчеркнуто-высоком стиле или с юмором - можно.